# Will custom attribute event be resent to Braze after device is active from offline

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying sending custom attribute event to Braze after some action in my app. But I'm not sure if the event will be re-sent if it is triggered during the device is offline and back to online.

Answer (score 0):

I just found Braze will handle it.